# ThreeJS rotation by X and Z axes doing the same rotation but in different direction

Tags: three.js

As far as I understood all rotations set via `object.rotation.x` / `object.rotation.y` / `object.rotation.z` are applied in respect to object's axes regardless of objects position in scene.

But in the code below after I set simple rotation value  `box.rotation.y = PI/2`
all subsequent changes to `box.rotation.x` seems to be rotating it not on `Box X Axis`  but on  `Box Z Axis` axis

If I will change `box.rotation.z`  it will still rotate on `Box Z Axis`  just in other direction.

So basically the problem is - rotation by `Box X Axis` and `Box Z Axis` doing the same rotation but in different direction.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I use rotation properly here e.g. if I want to apply rotation on `Box Z Axis` after rotation on `Box Y Axis`.

here I've created sandbox to reproduce the issue
https://stackblitz.com/edit/trhee-js-plane-rotation?file=index.js

[image]

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock.

Comment: @WestLangley is it what I have here? I thought gimbal lock is what I can face in much more complex situations

Answer (score 5):

You're running into gimbal lock, so you'll need [to use Quaternions](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Quaternion) to achieve the rotations you want. First you need to [set each quat from axis angle](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Quaternion.setFromAxisAngle), then you'll have to [multiply them together](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Quaternion.multiplyQuaternions) to get the desired rotation.

```
const xAxis = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
const xRot = -Math.PI;
const xQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
xQuaternion.setFromAxisAngle( xAxis, xRot );

const yAxis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
const yRot = Math.PI / 2;
const yQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
yQuaternion.setFromAxisAngle( yAxis, yRot );

box.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(xQuaternion, yQuaternion);
```

You could add a z-quaternion too using the same method as above, just make sure all 3 quats get multiplied at the end.

Comment: Depending on the use case, you can simply change the order of the rotations if you must rotate Y by pi / 2 : `box.rotation.order = 'YXZ';`